On Mobile Fields and Additional Fields section display nothing in the Salesforce1 mobile App
On Mobile Fields and Additional Fields section display nothing in the Salesforce1 mobile App on both Account and Knowledge Objects.
Why it is so? How this can be fixed?

The culprit of this issue was missing configuration and the fact we used Dynamic Forms.
So we just needed to follow this article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_on_mobile_enable.htm&type=5
and enabled Dynamic Forms on Mobile.

From Setup, in the Quick find box, enter Mobile, and then select
Salesforce Mobile App. Enable Dynamic Forms on Mobile.


